# Pasting all values with specific text under matching header

Tags: excel, vba

On Sheet1, I have a set of data with column A showing names and column B marital status.
I would like to output the name based on the marital status to Sheet2 where I have a predetermined dashboard (A1 could be start of table)

The data set will be dynamic and grow each time the vba is run

[image: raw set of data]

what I'd like the output data to be

[image: what I'd like the output data to be]

Would you kindly assist in the vba code for this output?

**Update, here is the code I have...which works but would like input on code efficiency**

```
Dim K As Long, r As Range, v As Variant
K = 1
Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet
Set w1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set w2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
w1.Activate
For Each r In Intersect(Range("B:B"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
    v = r.Value
    If InStr(v, "Divorced") > 0 Then 
        r.Offset(, -1).Copy w2.Cells(K + 3, 2)
        K = K + 1
    End If
Next r
K = 1
For Each r In Intersect(Range("B:B"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
    v = r.Value
    If InStr(v, "Married") > 0 Then
        r.Offset(, -1).Copy w2.Cells(K + 3, 3)
        K = K + 1
    End If
Next r
K = 1
For Each r In Intersect(Range("B:B"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
    v = r.Value
    If InStr(v, "Single") > 0 Then
        r.Offset(, -1).Copy w2.Cells(K + 3, 4)
        K = K + 1
    End If
Next r
K = 1
For Each r In Intersect(Range("B:B"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
    v = r.Value
    If InStr(v, "Widowed") > 0 Then
        r.Offset(, -1).Copy w2.Cells(K + 3, 5)
        K = K + 1
    End If
Next r
```

Comment: That's all doable.  I don't see a question though, just a list of requirements. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have edited the post, asking for the vba code to run this task. thank you

Comment: Unfortunately, you still haven't shown what you've tried so far.  Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), noting that you should not ask about "Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)".  If you're just looking for someone to do this for you, you've come to the wrong place.  If you have made an attempt, got stuck, and have a specific question, we are more than happy to help.

Comment: sorry, I didn't realize we couldn't just ask without trying. I've updated the code I've tried (works...but not sure if it is the best way to code it)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the best way to code it, here's how I would do it.  This ran about a million rows of data in 11 seconds.  Code commented for clarity.  Adjust the variable values to match your actual data where necessary.

**EDIT:** Added variable to allow for output column on wsDest to begin at defined column instead of assuming column `A`.  Set it to `B` to match OP's code.

```
Sub tgr()

    Const lDataHeaderRow As Long = 1    'The header row of your 2-column original data worksheet
    Const lDestHeaderRow As Long = 1    'The header row of your multi-column destination/output worksheet
    Const sDestStartCol As String = "B" 'The column letter where the output results begin

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim rDestHeaders As Range
    Dim hResults As Object
    Dim aData As Variant
    Dim aResults() As Variant
    Dim vTemp As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsData = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsDest = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set rDestHeaders = wsDest.Range(wsDest.Cells(lDestHeaderRow, sDestStartCol), wsDest.Cells(lDestHeaderRow, wsDest.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
    Set hResults = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'Use a dictionary to keep track of marital statuses and associated names

    'Define your data range here and load it into a variant array for processing
    With wsData.Range("A" & lDataHeaderRow + 1, wsData.Cells(wsData.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
        If .Row <= lDataHeaderRow Then Exit Sub   'No data
        ReDim aResults(1 To Evaluate("MAX(COUNTIF('" & wsData.Name & "'!B:B,'" & wsDest.Name & "'!" & rDestHeaders.Address & "))"), 1 To rDestHeaders.Cells.Count)
        aData = .Value
    End With

    'Define which column is for which header, the "|0" is the starting count found for that marital status
    For i = 1 To rDestHeaders.Cells.Count
        hResults(LCase(Trim(rDestHeaders.Cells(, i).Value))) = i & "|" & 0
    Next i

    'Loop through the variant array, looking at column 2 for the status
    For i = LBound(aData, 1) To UBound(aData, 1)
        'Verify column 1 and 2 and aren't blank
        If Len(Trim(aData(i, 1))) > 0 And Len(Trim(aData(i, 2))) > 0 Then
            'Verify current marital status (column 2) is listed in the destination headers
            If hResults.Exists(LCase(Trim(aData(i, 2)))) Then
                vTemp = Split(hResults(LCase(Trim(aData(i, 2)))), "|")
                vTemp(1) = vTemp(1) + 1
                aResults(vTemp(1), vTemp(0)) = aData(i, 1)
                hResults(LCase(Trim(aData(i, 2)))) = Join(vTemp, "|")
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    'Clear previous results
    Intersect(wsDest.Cells(lDestHeaderRow, sDestStartCol).CurrentRegion, rDestHeaders.EntireColumn).Offset(1).ClearContents

    'Output results
    wsDest.Cells(lDestHeaderRow + 1, sDestStartCol).Resize(UBound(aResults, 1), UBound(aResults, 2)).Value = aResults

End Sub
```